# Mysql user privilege for restore from mysqldump

Tags: mysql

What are the minimum privilege required for a mysql db user to use the mysqldump file and restore.

1. Cannot use root db user in my case.
2. Have taken full backup of all schemas in a dump file using mysqldump utility.
3. Need to know minimum required privileges to be given to a db user(other than root db user) so that it can be used to do restore from mysqldump file.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to restore a complete, unmodified dump file to a MySQL Server without the `SUPER` privilege.

The "root" user is not a magical user.  It just happens to be a user that is created by default and has `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* ... WITH GRANT OPTION`.  Another user can be given the same privileges.

Restoring a database essentially means obliterating everything on a server and replacing it with something else, including all the user accounts so `SUPER` is required.

More limited privileges can be used if certain modifications to the dump file are made, such as removing all `DEFINER` statements, and modifying the way the mysql schema is handled, but those modifications are an advanced topic with system-specific considerations.

Answer (score 3):

I've started with `SUPER`, `INSERT`, & `ALTER` and tried repeatedly adding new ones until the restore finished successfully.

This is what I've ended up with:

- `SUPER`
- `ALTER`
- `INSERT`
- `CREATE`
- `DROP`
- `LOCK TABLES`
- `REFERENCES`
- `SELECT`

If you have routines and triggers then you'll need these two additionally:

- `CREATE ROUTINE`
- `TRIGGER`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

From the Mysql official site:

> mysqldump requires at least the SELECT privilege for dumped tables,
>   SHOW VIEW for dumped views, TRIGGER for dumped triggers, and LOCK
>   TABLES if the --single-transaction option is not used. Certain options
>   might require other privileges as noted in the option descriptions.
>
> --single-transaction
>
> This option sets the transaction isolation mode to REPEATABLE READ and
>   sends a START TRANSACTION SQL statement to the server before dumping
>   data. It is useful only with transactional tables such as InnoDB,
>   because then it dumps the consistent state of the database at the time
>   when START TRANSACTION was issued without blocking any applications.

In conclusion, privileges are:

- select (required)
- lock tables (required)
- show views and trigger (optional)

Comment: The question is about restoring, not dumping.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thanks for pointing out, I didn't notice that.